# Using ACS in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2015, acs

**Question: How to configure ACS with Web API 4.5.2 project in Visual Studio 2015 ?**

Scenario:
I have created a WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2015 using ASP.Net Web API 4.5.2 template. My goal is to use ACS with this project.

I started with following example:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/

I have properly configured ACS namespace in the the Azure Management portal and using Windows live Id as the identity provider.
This example talks about using 'Identity and Access' tools for configuring ACS with the application.
*However, there is no such thing as 'Identity and Access' tools in VS 2015.*

*I have been searching about this for quite some time now and could not find any reference for using ACS with VS2015.
Even the code samples mentioned on ACS configuration portal in Azure site are not updated to reflect usage with VS2015.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385*

As such, I am stuck here. Any pointer for moving forward?

Comment: As per this official source, Azure Access Control Service (ACS) will be merged with Azure AD -http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory.aspx and I guess that changes the configuration process

Comment: I would recommend using Azure AD as per the above guidance.